# Ionic 2 : Refresh tabs view after adding a new dynamic tab

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic2

I'm using ionic tabs. Some tabs are generated from database (the ones without icons)

[image: ionic dynamic tabs]

Now when i add a new tab and refresh the array i should get 3 dynamic tabs. Instead i have 5 (the 2 previous ones and the 2 previous ones with the newest created tab) Despite the array correctly has 3 objects.

[image: Add dynamic tab]

[image: Dynamic tab added]

[Object, Object, Object]

[image]

So here the related code (the tabs component has an event that listen to a tab creation) :

```
// tabs.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DatabaseService } from "../../providers/database.service";

import { ItemsPage } from '../items/items';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { CategoryPage } from '../category/category';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  categories: any = [];

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = CategoryPage;
  tab3Root = ItemsPage;
  tab4Root = ContactPage;

  constructor(public databaseService: DatabaseService, public events: Events) {
      this.events.subscribe('category:created', () => {
      this.refreshTabs();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshTabs();
  }

  refreshTabs() {
    this.databaseService.getCategories().then(categories => {
      this.categories = categories;
      console.log(this.categories); // [Object, Object, Object]
    });
  }

}
```

So anytime i add or edit a tab i call :

this.events.publish('category:created');

tabs.html :

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="{{ category.name }}" [rootParams]="category.id" *ngFor="let category of categories"></ion-tab>
```

Any idea why the view on the tabs is incorrect?

**UPDATE :**

It seems using `this.category.push({id: 1, name: 'a category name'})` is working but i'd would rather refresh the entire array so i can order the way i want it from the sql query.

[Subject has been posted on ionic forum as well](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/refresh-tabs-view-after-adding-a-new-dynamic-tab/86757)

Comment: dynamic tabs seems to be open issue https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10632 and https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10805

Comment: Bummer ... Thank you for this information. Would the solution is to implement my own tabs? I don't really enjoy this solution but i guess i have no other choices, i can't afford to wait few weeks.

Comment: Have you tried Ionic page lifecycles instead?.  https://saniyusuf.com/ionic-by-component-page-lifecycle/ In the constructor you subscribe to the category:created Event. Do you need to unsubscribe and re--subscribe in the refresh perhaps, with the service call sandwiched in between?

Comment: Did get this working?

Comment: @JGFMK hi i did try it indeed but it didn't work.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa No it didn't i ended up creating my own tabs system. Not as good as the intended result of Ionic but that was the only fast solution i had.

Comment: @Brieuc, i am adding an answer, i am not sure but give it a shot.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa Sure, i'll not be able to test it since the project is done already. But sure you can propose something ;).

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering change detection manually -

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DatabaseService } from "../../providers/database.service";

import { ItemsPage } from '../items/items';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { CategoryPage } from '../category/category';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  categories: any = [];

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = CategoryPage;
  tab3Root = ItemsPage;
  tab4Root = ContactPage;

  constructor(public databaseService: DatabaseService, public events: Events, private ngZone: NgZone) {
      this.events.subscribe('category:created', () => {
      this.refreshTabs();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshTabs();
  }

  refreshTabs() {
    this.databaseService.getCategories().then(categories => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.categories = categories;
      console.log(this.categories); // [Object, Object, Object]
    });
  });
  }

}
```

Comment: I remember i tried something with NgZone and it didn't work at that time. Have you tried to test it? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your constructor to detect change and refresh your page.

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}

 refreshTabs() {
    this.databaseService.getCategories().then(categories => {
      this.categories = categories;
      console.log(this.categories); // [Object, Object, Object]
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
refreshTabs() {
    this.databaseService.getCategories().then(categories => {
      this.categories = categories;
      this.categories = [...this.categories]
      console.log(this.categories); // [Object, Object, Object]
    });
}
```

You can apply this.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this issue for now is to do this:

```
// Wherever you are calling push, refresh the tabs as well

// Like this: 

yourMethodWhereYouPush() {
  this.category.push({id: 1, name: 'a category name'}); 
  this.refreshTabs(); // Add this line so that once you push it, immediately the tabs will be refreshed with new data;
}
```